# Scrape the date from a HTML page

Tags: php, scraper

I am writing a PHP HTML page scraper program and I need to find out the date it has been updated.

I did this `$html = file_get_html(xyz.com)` to get the HTML. One line of the HTML has the date like this `&nbsp;10/24/2016`.

I did this:

```
if (strpos($html, '7nbsp;') !== false) {
    if (strpos($html, '&nbsp;</a>') !== false) {
      echo "How to print drawing date--here!";
    }
```

Now here is the dilemma, I cannot search `&nbsp;10/24/2016` because I have no way of knowing when the new date is when the site is updated, it could be 10/30/2016 or 11/12/2016...

Ideally, I would like the date to be in a string, like `$date = "11/17/2016"`.
How do I search the date itself?

Comment: Couldn't you just take the substring -10 from the end?

Comment: FYI, you have a typo in your code... `7nbsp;` vs `&nbsp;`.  Also, could you check headers instead?  There may be a usable date in the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you:

```
 preg_match('/\&nbsp;([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4})/', $html, $matches);
```

This is a regex that searches for a date (as long as the date is in correct format). Founded matches will be stored in '$matches' variable.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain clearly what I  want to do because I am very puzzled. Let me try again. What I want to do is to get the date itself. Let's say I want to use the &nbsp as a reference to confirm $html does contain the string &nbsp;10/24/2016, But a week later the date will be 10/31/2016 so surely I cannot use &nbsp;10/24/2016 as reference, the only thing I can use  for reference is &nbsp;. now how can I find 10/31/2016 and put it in a string. Is there a php can search a string start with &nbsp plus 10 more characters? That way I can use substring to get the correct date.

Comment: Yes this is what my code in the answer do. It is a regex that searches for a date (as long as the date is in correct format). Founded matches will be stored in '$matches' variable.

Answer (score 0):

@krasipenkov was close, but the OP asked for it to be in $date var:

```
$html = 'lblah
balh asdf asd 
<mickey mouse="disney">f3rt6wergsdfg &nbsp;1/19/2016 <more  stuff="here">etc
asdf';

preg_match('/\&nbsp;([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4})/', $html, $matches);
$date = $matches[1];

echo "your date found is $date";
```

[see it run] http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27419098cf4bc48a5ca2c683b046679b6c0af85c